# isSecureTextEntry Password TextField causes an error in displaying keyboard tips

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield

I'm working with some UITextFields to use the Email field and the Password field.

In the Password field I entered isSecureTextEntry = true
In the Email field I have suggestions for the user's email

Since I entered isSecureTextEntry in the password head, the suggestions in the Email field no longer appear

Have you also had this problem? is there a way to solve it?

Thank you all

if I change isSecureTextEntry from true to false ... everything works correctly ... I don't understand

---

[image: EMAIL BEFORE TAP ON PASSWORD TEXTFIELD]
[image: EMAIL AFTER PASSWORD TEXTFIELD TAPPED]

Comment: Check your iboutlet connection of both fields and both firstResponser also.

Comment: @AyazAkbar are connected correctly, if I change isSecureTextEntry from true to false ... everything works correctly ... I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is by design.

Note that in the second instance iOS is showing the "Password" button to access keychain passwords.

When iOS detects a username and password field pair it offers saved usernames/passwords rather than previously used emails on the basis that this is probably more useful.

If you set the secure text field content type to "new password" then iOS will infer that this is an account creation screen and will not offer saved passwords, but in my opinion this is a worse user experience.

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion. I set "new password" for the content type but also here if I select the textfield password and then subsequently select the textfield email the email suggestions are no longer displayed

Comment: at this point what would be the best way to create two "email" and "password" text fields without conflicting with each other? currently I can't use autofill because my app doesn't have a web domain to associate ...